# modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:838 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='off'

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 20.04, xorg, 4k-monitor

Having issues with **the system freezing on greeter with `modprobe nvidia`** and **`modprobe nouveau` failing to activate** after the addition of an "**NVIDIA GEFORCE GT 1030**" graphic card following a successful recent update from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. There are some serious issues relating to **nvidia and nouveau drivers** for the system configuration of graphic card to support a 4K UHD monitor for **all of the graphic interfaces** including those from PopOS.

Already spent 2 days doing all kind of things:

- Uninstalling & reinstalling all of the following (in different order and combinations): `gdm3`, `ubuntu-desktop`, `lightdm`, `nvidia-dkms-450`, `xserver-xorg`, `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`, `nouveau-firmware`
- Removed the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file

  - *Yes, I still had this file due to a different display I was using before.  It is best to remove this one so that Xorg can detect via the HAL the display resolutions*
- `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
- Installing a newer kernel `5.6.10`

  - Some people have reported that this solved the issue for them, not for me.
- Installing the current latest kernel 5.8.0 (me being hopeful, but that was not enough)
- Used `update-grub2` as I was editing the `/etc/default/grub` to use or not `nomodeset`

when Ubuntu starts and `hwinfo --gfxcard` says that "nvidia is active", the system freezes at the greeter and it is not possible to do anything other than a hard reset. At the same time is not possible to activate `nouveau` by using 'modrpobe nouveau'.

When executing `modprobe nouveau`:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:838 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='off'<br>
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'off': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

This is despite the nouveau driver being installed (however I doubt the installation did its job.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Full solution:**

`modprobe nouveau` can start working after running in recovery mode as root:

> apt remove --purge nvidia-driver-450
> reboot

However, the system still does not start and freezes at the greeter.
Basically for some reason, I had to remove the nvidia driver in order to have the nouveau driver to activate. Not ideal but might lead someone in the right direction towards solving this puzzle.

**I figured out that the system was not freezing**, it was something to do with **the keyboard and mouse no longer being detected once the GUI interface starts** (really weird, that explains why there were not any specific logs, hence me initially looking at the graphic card drivers).

**The solution works with the latest kernel 5.8.0 and nvidia-driver-450**
even working with two 4K displays, the downfall is the support for virtualbox by this kernel

> sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-all
> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all

After rebooting everything is working as normal with the nvidia drivers, hence no need to use the nouveau driver, but good to know all of it anyway ;)